# Spark: Reading CSV files from list of paths in a DataFrame Row

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Spark DataFrame as follows:

```
# ---------------------------------
# - column 1 - ...  -   column 5  -
# ---------------------------------
# - ...             - Array of paths
```

Columns 1 to 4 contain strings and the fifth column contains list of strings, that are actually paths to CSV files I wish to read as Spark Dataframes. I cannot find anyway to read them. Here's a simplified version with just a single column and the column with the list of paths:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,Row

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName('test') \
        .getOrCreate()

simpleRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(range(10))
simpleRDD = simpleRDD.map(lambda x: Row(**{'a':x,'paths':['{}_{}.csv'.format(y**2,y+1) for y in range(x+1)]}))

simpleDF = spark.createDataFrame(simpleRDD)
print(simpleDF.head(5))
```

This gives:

```
[Row(a=0, paths=['0_1.csv']),  
 Row(a=1, paths=['0_1.csv', '1_2.csv']),  
 Row(a=2, paths=['0_1.csv', '1_2.csv', '4_3.csv']),  
 Row(a=3, paths=['0_1.csv', '1_2.csv', '4_3.csv', '9_4.csv']),  
 Row(a=4, paths=['0_1.csv', '1_2.csv', '4_3.csv', '9_4.csv', '16_5.csv'])]
```

I would like then to do something like this:

```
simpleDF = simpleDF.withColumn('data',spark.read.csv(simpleDF.paths))
```

...but this of course, does not work.

Comment: Firstly, please format your input `DataFrame` properly. Secondly, Add in list of paths in `DataFrame Row`.

Comment: There is a list of paths in the DataFrame Row ('paths': ...). The whole point is that this list of paths, depends on what is in the other column. The DataFrame format I gave was just an example, it is irrelevant to the question's goal.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,Row

from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName('test') \
        .getOrCreate()

inp=[['a','b','c','d',['abc\t1.txt','abc\t2.txt','abc\t3.txt','abc\t4.txt','abc\t5.txt',]],
            ['f','g','h','i',['def\t1.txt','def\t2.txt','def\t3.txt','def\t4.txt','def\t5.txt',]],
            ['k','l','m','n',['ghi\t1.txt','ghi\t2.txt','ghi\t3.txt','ghi\t4.txt','ghi\t5.txt',]]
           ]

inp_data=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(inp)

##Defining the schema

schema = StructType([StructField('field1',StringType(),True),
                      StructField('field2',StringType(),True),
                      StructField('field3',StringType(),True),
                      StructField('field4',StringType(),True),
                      StructField('field5',ArrayType(StringType(),True))
                     ])

## Create the Data frames

dataframe=spark.createDataFrame(inp_data,schema)
dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("dataframe")
dataframe.select("field5").filter("field1='a'").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you intend to store the `DataFrame` objects once you read them in from their path, but if it's a matter of *accessing* the values in your `DataFrame` column, you can use the `.collect()` method to return your `DataFrame` as a list of `Row` objects (just like an `RDD`).

Each `Row` object has a `.asDict()` method that converts it to a Python `dictionary` object. Once you're there, you can access the values by indexing the dictionary using its key.

Assuming you're content storing the returned `DataFrames` in a list, you could try the following:

```
# collect the DataFrame into a list of Rows
rows = simpleRDD.collect()

# collect all the values in your `paths` column
# (note that this will return a list of lists)

paths = map(lambda row: row.asDict().get('paths'), rows)

# flatten the list of lists
paths_flat = [path for path_list in paths for path in path_list]

# get the unique set of paths 
paths_unique = list(set(paths_flat))

# instantiate an empty dictionary in which to collect DataFrames

dfs_dict = []
for path in paths_unique:
    dfs_dict[path] = spark.read.csv(path)
```

Your `dfs_dict` will now contain all of your `DataFrames`. To get the `DataFrame` of a particular path, you can access it using the path as the dictionary key:

```
df_0_01 = dfs_dict['0_1.csv']
```